# PHP - REST - Slim Framework HTTP Basic Auth - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, rest, authentication, frameworks, slim

I want to implement HTTP-Basic-Authentication in my REST API (PHP - Slim Framework).
If I send a POST Request to the protected URL, it shows a window 'Authentication required', where I can fill in my credentials, but I always get an error 
*401 Unauthorized*.

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
"path" => "/api/v1/video/add",
"realm" => "Protected",
"secure" => false,
"users" => [
    "root" => "root123",
    "user" => "user"
]
]));
```

route:

```
$app->post('/api/v1/video/add', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

// get POST-Variables
$allPostVars = $request->getParsedBody(); 
$id = $allPostVars['id'];
[....]
}
```

Comment: Can you show example curl request how you access your api.Something like: $ curl --include --user root:root123 --request POST http://example.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implement Basic Auth, then use https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth.